# How can I find my categorical inputs shape?

Tags: python, neural-network

I have built a Neural Network model with 2 inputs. I have attempted to convert two variables into categorical. When I run the program I got the following error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected meta_input to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1109,)

How can I find the shape to use? below is part of my program:

```
input_encoder = MultiColumnLabelEncoder()
train_X2=df_train[['var2','var3']]
valid_X2 =df_valid[['var2','var3']]
input_encoder.fit(train_X2)
train_X2=input_encoder.transform(train_X2)
valid_X2=input_encoder.transform(valid_X2)
onehot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,categories='auto')
onehot.fit(train_X2)
train _seq=onehot.transform(train_X2)
valid _seq =onehot.transform(valid_X2)

input_text = Input(shape=(200,), dtype='int32', name='input_text')
meta_input = Input(shape=(2,), name='meta_input')
embedding = Embedding(input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 
              output_dim=300, 
              input_length=200)(input_text)

lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, 
                  dropout=0.5, 
                  recurrent_dropout=0.5, 
                  return_sequences=True),
             merge_mode='concat')(embedding)
pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(lstm)
dropout = Dropout(0.5)(pool)
text_output = Dense(n_codes, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(dropout)

output = concatenate([text_output, meta_input])
output = Dense(n_codes, activation='relu')(output)

main_output = Dense(n_codes, activation='softmax', name='main_output')(output)

model = Model(inputs=[input_text,meta_input], outputs=[output])
optimer = Adam(lr=.001)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
      loss='binary_crossentropy', 
      metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.fit([X1_train, X2_train], [y_train],
  validation_data=([X1_valid,X2_valid], [y_valid]),
  batch_size=64, epochs=20, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with: "shape=X2_train.shape[1]"